# Why does the statement hold true for subsequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a real-valued bounded sequence.
Assume $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(a_{2 n}-2 a_{n}\right)=0$
Assume $w$ is an accumulation point of the sequence $a_{n}$.

I've seen the professor using the following statement $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(a_{2 \psi(n)}-2 a_{\psi (n)}\right)=0$
But why does it hold true ?

Comment: Maybe it could help setting $b_n:=a_{2n}-2a_n$. Then $b_n\to0$ and you want to justify why $b_{\psi(n)}\to0$ as well.

Comment: What is $\psi(n)$?

Comment: All subsequences of a convergent sequence converge (to the same limit).

Comment: If all subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit, then does that mean that all convergent sequences have only 1 accumulation point?